# Using FILESTREAM to write and read the image from the database

Tags: sql-server-2008, vb6, filestream

I have made database in SQL SERVER 2008 and have enabled the filestream technique. Now, how can I save the image to the SQL Server from vb 6.0. My database query for filesstream is as follows:

```
CREATE DATABASE Photo;

GO

ALTER DATABASE Photo
ADD FILEGROUP PhotoDBFS CONTAINS FILESTREAM;

GO

DECLARE @FilePath varchar(MAX) = (SELECT SUBSTRING(physical_name, 1, CHARINDEX(N'master.mdf',     LOWER(physical_name)) - 1)
              FROM master.sys.master_files
              WHERE database_id = 1 AND file_id = 1) + 'PhotoDBFS_Filestream';


DECLARE @SQL varchar(MAX) = '
ALTER DATABASE Photo ADD FILE (
   NAME = PhotoDBFSFile,
   FILENAME = ''' + @FilePath + ''')
TO FILEGROUP PhotoDBFS;';
EXECUTE(@SQL);

GO
```

My table structure where I want to save the image is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Photos
(
PhotoId                 bigint                      NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
Title                   varchar(100)                NOT NULL DEFAULT(''),
Subject                 varchar(100)                NOT NULL DEFAULT('No Subject'),
Place                   varchar(100)                NOT NULL DEFAULT('Unknown'),
Comment                 varchar(1000)                   NULL DEFAULT(''),
Rating                  tinyint                     NOT NULL DEFAULT(0),
PhotoFile               varbinary(MAX)  FILESTREAM  NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PhotoRatingCheck CHECK(Rating >=0 AND Rating<=10)
);
```

My vb code for saving the image is as follows:

```
'Saving in the table [Photos]
Set Rs = New Recordset
SqlString = "SELECT * FROM Photos"
Rs.Open SqlString, con, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
Rs.AddNew
    Rs("UniqueId") = txtUniqueId.Text
    Rs("CategoryId") = tempCategoryId
    Rs("AlbumId") = tempAlbumId
    Rs("Title") = txtTitle.Text
    Rs("Subject") = txtSubject.Text
    Rs("Place") = txtPlace.Text
    Rs("Comment") = txtComment.Text
    Rs("Rating") = sliderRating.Value
    Rs("PhotoFile") = PhotoLocation
Rs.Close
Set Rs = Nothing
```

I get this error while saving.
**Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.**

I also want to read the saved image from the database. Any suggestion???

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? You didn't say.

Comment: @Oded: I am not able to save the photo in Photos.PhotoFile. Do you know how to save the image using the above query from the vb 6?

Comment: Errors? Exceptions? The code that doesn't work? More detail is needed.

Comment: @Oded: See the question, i have edited it.

Comment: What is `PhotoLocation`? Is it a string?

Comment: @Oded: Yes it is a string that holds the location of the selected photo.

Comment: `Rs("PhotoFile")` is supposed to hold the _content_ of the file, not the location. You need to open the file and transfer the _content_ in.

Comment: @Oded: How to do so? Can you tell me the process?

Comment: @Kushal - It has been a long time since I have used VB6. Wait for someone with more recent experience. In the meantime update your question to contain as much relevant information as possible. You still didn't ask a proper question on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update `IDENTITY` columns, so remove assignment on `UniqueId` field, this fails now for certain.

When accessing the BLOB column `PhotoFile` sometimes helps to be explicit using `Value` property of the `Field` object i.e. `Rs!PhotoFile.Value = binaryData` or `Rs("PhotoFile").Value = binaryData`

Comment: Try using client-side recordset then.

Answer (score 0):

For a table to have one or more FILESTREAM columns, it must also have a column of the uniqueidentifier data type that has the ROWGUIDCOL attribute. Does the CREATE TABLE statement you pasted in the question even work?

Comment: The SQL query works perfectly, but I am having problem in VB. I get this error while saving. "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done." while trying to save the picture.